# Animating a UIViewController in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm new to iOS Dev and wanted to ask a question. I don't know if it's been answered in Objective-C, but I didn't find any swift 3 implementations of it.

The gif link is as follows : [http://i.imgur.com/zLa2YZu.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/zLa2YZu.gifv)

I would like to duplicate the same functionality using UICollectionViews, when the user taps on a "cell". The overlay animating view, with a collectionView up top and an image on the bottom.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

So I can help you out as far as giving hints about directions you'll want to go:

- The overlay should be a UIViewController. You can give it the CGRect of where the element is on screen that you want to animate from, and then either implement a custom transition, or call a function that animates from that point.
- Your view controller will have a collection view at the top, and then a view below it which is laid out to contain all the info about the element.
- The collection view items being tapped will cause a new element to be given to the view at the bottom, by the UIViewController.